# Is it possible to prove that f(n) + g(n) = theta(n^2) for f(n) = theta(n^2) & g(n) = O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there any way to prove that

```
f(n) + g(n) = theta(n^2)
```

Or it is impossible?
Assuming `f(n) = theta(n^2) & g(n) = O(n^2)`

I tried the following: f(n) = O(n^2) & g(n) = O(n^2). I proved that

```
0 <= f(n) <= c1*n^2 
0 <= f(n) <= c2*n^2
for c1 > 1 & c2 > 1
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework and you have not shown what you attempted like http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic says you should.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a math proof, not a programming question.  Maybe try Math.SX?

Comment: @JAL I think that's a bit unfair. It's a basic math proof that only requires knowledge directly related to the standard proof methods for the complexity of algorithms.

Comment: @Synergist Read through dozens of posts on meta (such as [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285606/why-have-math-tag/285607#285607)) that discuss how math questions are off-topic for SO.  If there was a programming component to this question, then it would be acceptable.  But right now in its current state it is off-topic.

Comment: @JAL fair enough, I stand corrected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can prove it.

- `f(n)` is in `Theta(n^2)`, so there exists constants `c1,c2,N`, such
  that for all `n>N1` f(n) is bounded: `c1*n^2 <= f(n) <= c2*n^2` (by
  definiton)
- `g(n)` is in `O(n^2)`, so there exist constants `c3,N2` such that for all `n>N2`, g(n) is bounded: `g(n) <= c3*n^2` (by definition)

Now, have a look at `f(n)+g(n)` for `n>max{N1,N2}`:

```
f(n) + g(n) <= c2*n^2 + c3*n^2 = (c2+c3)*n^2
```

Also,assuming `f(n)` is non-negative, `c1*n^2 <= f(n) <= f(n) + g(n)`, again for `n>max{N1,N2}>=N1`.

We got that for `N=max{N1,N2}`, there exists constants `c=c1, c'=(c2+c3)`, such that for all n>N

```
c*n^2 <= f(n) + g(n) <= c'*n^2
```

By definition of big Theta, this means `f(n)+g(n)` is in `Theta(n^2)`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to prove or disprove whether

```
Premise: f(n) = theta(n^2), and g(n) = O(n^2)
```

is sufficient for

```
Conclusion: f(n) + g(n) = theta(n^2)
```

I'll be happy to help you analyze your attempts at proving it...if you show such an attempt.

Comment: I tried the following: f(n) = O(n^2) & g(n) = O(n^2). I proved that 0 <= f(n) <= c1*n^2 & 0 <= f(n) <= c2*n^2, for c1 > 1 & c2 > 1

Comment: The problem with f(n) = Ω(n^2) & g(n) = O(n^2). What I think it is impossible!!

Comment: Firstly, formalize your notation with setting `h(n) = f(n) + g(n)`. Then what two inequalities involving `h(n)` must you show to verify whether `h(n)` is `theta(n^2)`?

Comment: I think, 0 <= c1*n^2 <= h(n) <= c2*n^2

Comment: Good. So you know there exists constants `c_f1, c_f2, c_g, n_f, n_g` satisfying `c_f1 * n^2 <= f(n) <= c_f2 * n^2` for `n >= n_f`, and `g(n) <= c_g * n^2` for `n >= n_g`. Now use those inequalities to find suitable `c1` and `c2` and `n_h` constants to prove `h(n) = theta(n^2)`, or show that no such constants can exist.

Comment: do you mean, c_f1 < 1 & c_f2 > 1 & c_g > 1. But how can relate those to the 0 <= c1*n^2 <= h(n) <= c2*n^2? This is the problem that I'm struggling with.